# C++ LRU cache - need suggestions on how to improve speed

Tags: c++, algorithm, lru

The task is to implement an O(1) Least Recently Used Cache

Here is the question on leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/

Here is my solution, while it is O(1) it is not the fastest implementation
could you give some feedback and maybe ideas on how can I optimize this ? Thank you !

```cpp
#include<unordered_map>
#include<list>

class LRUCache {

    // umap<key,<value,listiterator>>
    // store the key,value, position in list(iterator) where push_back occurred
private:
    unordered_map<int,pair<int,list<int>::iterator>> umap;
    list<int> klist;  
    int cap = -1;

public:
    LRUCache(int capacity):cap(capacity){

    }

    int get(int key) {
        // if the key exists in the unordered map
        if(umap.count(key)){
            // remove it from the old position 
            klist.erase(umap[key].second);
            klist.push_back(key);
            list<int>::iterator key_loc = klist.end();
            umap[key].second = --key_loc;
            return umap[key].first;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    void put(int key, int value) {

        // if key already exists delete it from the the umap and klist
        if(umap.count(key)){
            klist.erase(umap[key].second);
            umap.erase(key);
        }
        // if the unordered map is at max capacity
        if(umap.size() == cap){
            umap.erase(klist.front());
            klist.pop_front();
        }
        // finally update klist and umap
        klist.push_back(key);
        list<int>::iterator key_loc = klist.end();
        umap[key].first = value;
        umap[key].second = --key_loc;
        return;
    }
};

/**
 * Your LRUCache object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * LRUCache* obj = new LRUCache(capacity);
 * int param_1 = obj->get(key);
 * obj->put(key,value);
 */
```

Comment: the map size should technically never cross the capacity otherwise that is a faulty design

Comment: Makes sense from real OS perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some optimizations that might help:

Take this segment of code from the `get` function:

```
    if(umap.count(key)){
        // remove it from the old position 
        klist.erase(umap[key].second);
```

The above will lookup `key` in the map twice. Once for the `count` method to see if it exists.  Another to invoke the `[]` operator to fetch its value.  Save a few cycles by doing this:

```
auto itor = umap.find(key);
if (itor != umap.end()) {
        // remove it from the old position 
        klist.erase(itor->second);
```

In the `put` function, you do this:

```
    if(umap.count(key)){
        klist.erase(umap[key].second);
        umap.erase(key);
    }
```

Same thing as `get`, you can avoid the redundant search through `umap`. Additionally, there's no reason to invoke `umap.erase` only to add that same key back into the map a few lines later.

Further, this is also inefficient

```
    umap[key].first = value;
    umap[key].second = --key_loc;
```

Similar to above, redundantly looking up `key` twice in the map.  In the first assignment statement, the `key` is not in the map, so it default constructs a new value pair thing. The second assignment is doing another lookup in the map.

Let's restructure your `put` function as follows:

```
void put(int key, int value) {

    auto itor = umap.find(key);
    bool reinsert = (itor != umap.end());

    // if key already exists delete it from the klist only
    if (reinsert) {
        klist.erase(umap[key].second);
    }
    else {
        // if the unordered map is at max capacity
        if (umap.size() == cap) {
            umap.erase(klist.front());
            klist.pop_front();
        }
    }

    // finally update klist and umap
    klist.push_back(key);
    list<int>::iterator key_loc = klist.end();
    auto endOfList = --key_loc;

    if (reinsert) {
        itor->second.first = value;
        itor->second.second = endOfList;
    }
    else  {
        const pair<int, list<int>::iterator> itempair = { value, endOfList };
        umap.emplace(key, itempair);
    }
}
```

That's as far as you can probably go by using `std::list`.  The downside of the `list` type is that there's no way to move an existing node from the middle to the front (or back) without first removing it and then adding it back. That's a couple of unneeded memory allocations to update the list.  Possible alternative is that you just use your own double-linked list type and manually fixup the prev/next pointer yourself.

Comment: You can use [std::list::splice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) to move a node within the same list including to the front or back.

Comment: @selbie Thank you !! I tried your suggestions, although the code improved it now runs in 172ms instead of 184ms, also how is umap.emplace(key,itempair) different from umap[key] = itempair. as I understood unordered_map the inserts and look ups are O(1) .

Comment: @Blastfurnace trying your way with klist.splice(klist.end(),klist,it->second.second); gives me [ AddressSanitizer : alloc-dealloc-mismatch. ] Is this the right way to move an intermediate node to the back of the list ?

Comment: @auxeon That looks correct. I'm not in a place where I can test anything but [this is the code](https://godbolt.org/z/a6XTf9) that I used and is accepted on LeetCode. Note that I'm splicing to the front but splicing to the back should also work.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my solution, while it is O(1) it is not the fastest implementation
>   could you give some feedback and maybe ideas on how can I optimize this ? Thank you !

Gonna take on selbie's point here: 
Every instance of `if(umap.count(key))` will search for the key and using `umap[key]` is the equivalent for the search. You can avoid the double search by assigning an iterator which points to the key by a single `std::unordered_map::find()` operation.

selbie already gave the code for `int get()`'s search, here's the one for `void put()`'s one:

```cpp
auto it = umap.find(key);
if (it != umap.end()) 
{
    klist.erase(it ->second);
    umap.erase(key);
}
```

---

Sidecase:

Not applicable for your code as of now due to lack of input and output work, but in case you use `std::cin` and `std::cout`, you can disable the synchronization between C and C++ streams, and untie cin from cout as an optimization: (they are tied together by default)

```cpp
// If your using cin/cout or I/O
ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(nullptr);
cout.tie(nullptr);
```

Comment: How do those `cin.tie` and `cout.tie` calls improve performance for this particular code which does no I/O at all?

Comment: @selbie Right! (I quickly looked up the code and assumed an instance of cin/cout) Edited